# How to read until EOF from cin in C++

Tags: c++, input, iostream

I am coding a program that reads data directly from user input and was wondering how could I (without loops) read all data until EOF from standard input. I was considering using `cin.get( input, '\0' )` but `'\0'` is not really the EOF character, that just reads until EOF or `'\0'`, whichever comes first.

Or is using loops the only way to do it? If so, what is the best way?

Answer (score 99):

The only way you can read a variable amount of data from `stdin` is using loops. I've always found that the [`std::getline()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) function works very well:

```
std::string line;
while (std::getline(std::cin, line))
{
    std::cout << line << std::endl;
}
```

By default `getline()` reads until a newline. You can specify an alternative termination character, but EOF is not itself a character so you cannot simply make one call to `getline()`.

Comment: Something to be careful of here is when you're reading from files that have been piped in via stdin, is that this and most of the answers given will append an extra line feed on the end of your input.  Not all files end with a line feed, yet each iteration of the loop appends "std::endl" to the stream.   This may not be an issue in most cases, but if file integrity is an issue, this may come back to bite you.

Comment: This should not be the most upvoted answer. See the below community wiki answer. Also, maybe see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3203452/how-to-read-entire-stream-into-a-stdstring

Answer (score 71):

Using loops:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
...
// numbers
int n;
while (cin >> n)
{
   ...
}
// lines
string line;
while (getline(cin, line))
{
   ...
}
// characters
char c;
while (cin.get(c))
{
   ...
}
```

[resource](http://acm.timus.ru/help.aspx?topic=cpp)

Answer (score 58):

You can do it without explicit loops by using stream iterators.  I'm sure that it uses some kind of loop internally.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <istream>
#include <ostream>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
// don't skip the whitespace while reading
  std::cin >> std::noskipws;

// use stream iterators to copy the stream to a string
  std::istream_iterator<char> it(std::cin);
  std::istream_iterator<char> end;
  std::string results(it, end);

  std::cout << results;
}
```

Comment: Nice.  As for "I'm sure that it uses some kind of loop internally" - any solution would.

Comment: This seems to remove newline characters from input, even if they occur right in the middle.

Answer (score 46):

After researching KeithB's solution using `std::istream_iterator`, I discovered the [`std:istreambuf_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istreambuf_iterator).

Test program to read all piped input into a string, then write it out again:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>

int main()
{
  std::istreambuf_iterator<char> begin(std::cin), end;
  std::string s(begin, end);
  std::cout << s;
}
```

Comment: This should probably be the canonical answer.

Comment: Downvoted. So what are the pros or cons compared to KeithB's solution? Yes, you are using an `std::istreambuf_iterator` instead of an `std::istream_iterator`, but what for?

Comment: std::istreambuf_iterator skips whitespace by default and can be faster

Answer (score 7):

Probable simplest and generally efficient:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    std::cout << std::cin.rdbuf();
}
```

If needed, use stream of other types like `std::ostringstream` as buffer instead of standard output stream here.

Comment: you guys already know, but may be helpful to some: `std::ostringstream std_input; std_input  << std::cin.rdbuf(); std::string s = std_input.str()` . you have all the input in `s` (be careful with  `std::string` if the input is too big)

Answer (score 4):

Sad side note: I decided to use C++ IO to be consistent with boost based code. From answers to this question I chose `while (std::getline(std::cin, line))`. Using g++ version 4.5.3 (-O3) in cygwin (mintty) i got 2 MB/s throughput. Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 (/O2) made it 40 MB/s for the same code.

After rewriting the IO to pure C `while (fgets(buf, 100, stdin))` the throughput jumped to 90 MB/s in both tested compilers. That makes a difference for any input bigger than 10 MB...

Comment: No need to rewrite your code to pure C, just add a `std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);` before your while-loop. `cin.tie(NULL);` may also help if you interleave reading and writing.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [std::istream::getline()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/getline.html) (or preferably the [version that works on std::string](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/string/getline)) function to get an entire line.  Both have versions that allow you to specify the delimiter (end of line character).  The default for the string version is '\n'.

Answer (score 1):

Wait, am I understanding you correctly?  You're using cin for keyboard input, and you want to stop reading input when the user enters the EOF character?  Why would the user ever type in the EOF character?  Or did you mean you want to stop reading from a file at the EOF?

If you're actually trying to use cin to read an EOF character, then why not just specify the EOF as the delimiter?

```
// Needed headers: iostream

char buffer[256];
cin.get( buffer, '\x1A' );
```

If you mean to stop reading from a file at the EOF, then just use getline and once again specify the EOF as the delimiter.

```
// Needed headers: iostream, string, and fstream

string buffer;

    ifstream fin;
    fin.open("test.txt");
    if(fin.is_open()) {
        getline(fin,buffer,'\x1A');

        fin.close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while(std::cin) {
 // do something
}
```

Comment: This is a terrible disaster of an answer, since it's virtually guaranteed to result in wrong code.

Comment: @KerrekSB why it's virtually guaranteed to result in wrong code?

Comment: @MatúšFerech: Because it strongly suggests that `// do something` does not contain additional checks of return values of I/O operations, and the check it does contain is meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to a use a container, e.g.

```
std::vector<char> data;
```

and *redirect* all input into this collection until `EOF` is received, i.e.

```
std::copy(std::istream_iterator<char>(std::cin),
    std::istream_iterator<char>(),
    std::back_inserter(data));
```

However, the used container might need to reallocate memory too often, or you will end with a `std::bad_alloc` exception when your system gets out of memory. In order to solve these problems, you could *reserve* a fixed amount `N` of elements and process these amount of elements in isolation, i.e.

```
data.reserve(N);    
while (/*some condition is met*/)
{
    std::copy_n(std::istream_iterator<char>(std::cin),
        N,
        std::back_inserter(data));

    /* process data */

    data.clear();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One line for loop:

```
for( std::string line; std::getline(std::cin, line); std::cout << line << std::endl );
```