# How to read entire stream into a std::vector?

Tags: c++, vector, stl, stream, ifstream

I read [an answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3203502/416274) showing how to  read an entire stream into a std::string with the following one (two) liner:

```
std::istreambuf_iterator<char> eos;    
std::string s(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(stream), eos);
```

For doing something similar to read a binary stream into a `std::vector`, why can't I simply replace `char` with `uint8_t` and `std::string` with `std::vector`?

```
auto stream = std::ifstream(path, std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);    
auto eos = std::istreambuf_iterator<uint8_t>();
auto buffer = std::vector<uint8_t>(std::istreambuf_iterator<uint8_t>(stream), eos);
```

The above produces a compiler error (VC2013):

> 1>d:\non-svn\c++\library\i\file\filereader.cpp(62): error C2440:
>   '' : cannot convert from
>   'std::basic_ifstream>' to
>   'std::istreambuf_iterator>' 1>
>   with 1>          [ 1>              _Elem=uint8_t 1>          ] 1>
>   No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload
>   resolution was ambiguous

Comment: Based on the error message, `char` and `uint8_t` are not the same thing on your compiler. Try using `char` instead.

Comment: @cdhowie `uint8_t` is `unsigned char`, so yes, not the same thing on any computer ;) But yeah, it's probably an ambiguous cast, since the output for `ifstream` is ``char``.

Comment: Yes, it works with char but uint8_t is unsigned char anyway.

Comment: @Robinson: Exactly. `char` and `unsigned char` are different types.

Comment: @cdhowie `char`, `signed char` and `unsigned char` are always 3 distinct types.

Comment: OK I get it.  My bad.  I'm trying to achieve a distinct meaning between std::vector<char> and std::vector<uint8_t>.  The former is always text, the latter is always binary data.  I see my error now.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There's just a type mismatch. `ifstream` is just a typedef:

```
typedef basic_ifstream<char> ifstream;
```

So if you want to use a different underlying type, you just have to tell it:

```
std::basic_ifstream<uint8_t> stream(path, std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);    
auto eos = std::istreambuf_iterator<uint8_t>();
auto buffer = std::vector<uint8_t>(std::istreambuf_iterator<uint8_t>(stream), eos);
```

That works for me.

Or, since Dietmar says this might be a little sketchy, you could do something like:

```
auto stream = std::ifstream(...);
std::vector<uint8_t> data;

std::for_each(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(stream),
              std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(),
              [&data](const char c){
                  data.push_back(c);
              });
```

Comment: It is quite surprising if that actually works! It _may_ compile but I can't imagine that this runs readily out of the box: creating a stream for a character type other than `char` or `wchar_t` certainly doesn't have to work right away as quite a number of the necessary facets doesn't have to be provided. For the specific need I'd expect that at least `std::codecvt<uint8_t, char, std::mbstate_t>` is missing (I'm not sure if any other facet is really required).

Comment: If it's not supposed to work out of the box I suppose I shouldn't be doing it.  What I'd like is to distinguish between a binary stream and binary data and text stream and text data.  So I was going to use uint8_t for binary data and char for text.  I suppose it's idiomatic to use char for everything...

Comment: You could simply use typedefs like ``typedef std::vector<char> text_vector`` and ``typedef std::vector<char> binary_vector``. While they're the same type under the hood, at least your code becomes self-documenting in terms of what kind of data you expect where.

Comment: Yes, I think I may do that.

Comment: The easiest approach is to just use `std::istreambuf_iterator<char>` to initialize the `std::vector<uint8_t>`.

Answer (score 6):

`ifstream` is a stream of `char`, not `uint8_t`. You'll need either `basic_ifstream<uint8_t>` or `istreambuf_iterator<char>` for the types to match.

The former may not work without some amount of work, since the library is only required to support streams of `char` and `wchar_t`; so you probably want `istreambuf_iterator<char>`.

Comment: ... and creating a `std::basic_ifstream<uint8_t>` is rather non-trivial!

Comment: @DietmarKühl: Good point. I generally avoid the murky depths of the I/O library, so can't remember exactly what it supports.