# How to get rid of no "matching function call error" when iterating over a stream buffer?

Tags: c++, iteration

I am trying to store binary data that should have the type of a std::complex< float > into a vector, through iterating over each element of the stream buffer. However I keep getting an error saying

```
no matching function for call to ‘std::istreambuf_iterator<std::complex<float> >::istreambuf_iterator(std::ifstream&)’
 std::for_each(std::istreambuf_iterator<std::complex<float> >(i_f1),
```

I've tried searching for a solution but cannot find anything that would work. I am also trying to follow an example given in [How to read entire stream into a std::vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26589317/how-to-read-entire-stream-into-a-stdvector) . Furthermore I'm compiling using g++ and -std=c++11.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <boost/tuple/tuple.hpp>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

int main(){

    //path to files
    std::string data_path= "/$HOME/some_path/";

    //file to be opened
    std::string f_name1 = "ch1_d2.dat";


    std::ifstream i_f1(data_path + f_name1, std::ios::binary);
    if (!i_f1){
        std::cout << "Error occurred reading file "<<f_name1 <<std::endl;        std::cout << "Exiting" << std::endl;
        return 0;
     } 

    //Place buffer contents into vector 
    std::vector<std::complex<float> > data1;

    std::for_each(std::istreambuf_iterator<std::complex<float> >(i_f1), 
        std::istreambuf_iterator<std::complex<float> >(), 
        [&data1](std::complex<float> vd){
        data1.push_back(vd);
        });

   // Test to see if vector was read in correctly
   for (auto i = data1.begin(); i != data1.end(); i++){
        std::cout << *i << " ";

    }

    i_f1.close();
    return 0;
}
```

I am quite lost at what I'm doing wrong, and am thus wondering why the

```
std::istreambuf_iterator()
```

does not accept the stream I am giving it as parameter?
Also the error message is confusing me as it seems to imply that I am calling the function in a wrong way, or a function that is non-existent.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to read `std::complex` from `i_f1` (which is a `std::ifstream`) using [`operator>>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex/operator_ltltgtgt) for `std::complex`, so you need a [`std::istream_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator) instead of `std::istreambuf_iterator`<sup>1</sup>:

```
std::for_each(std::istream_iterator<std::complex<float> >(i_f1), 
    std::istream_iterator<std::complex<float> >(), 
    [&data1](std::complex<float> vd){
        data1.push_back(vd);
    });
```

Your code can actually be simplified to:

```
std::vector<std::complex<float>> data1{
    std::istream_iterator<std::complex<float>>(i_f1), 
    std::istream_iterator<std::complex<float>>()};
```

<sub><sup>1</sup> `std::istreambuf_iterator` is used to iterate character per character on, e.g., a `std::basic_istream`, not to iterate over it using overloads of `operator>>`.</sub>

Comment: Actually, istreambuf_iterator can quite deliberately be instantiated from an std::istream& ... but it has to have the same character type.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Thanks, I've actually never used `streambuf_iterator` so I did not know its really use. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 4):

You're probably using the wrong tool for the job.

You're trying to use a *buffer iterator*, which iterates over the constituent parts of a stream's *buffer*. But you're telling your computer that the buffer is one of `complex<float>`s … it isn't. An `ifstream`'s buffer is of `char`s. Hence the constructor you're trying to use (one that takes an `ifstream` with a buffer of `complex<float>`) does not exist.

You can use an `istream_iterator` to perform a *formatted* iteration, i.e. to use the stream's magical powers (in this case, lexically interpreting input as `complex<float>`s) rather than directly accessing its underlying bytes.

You can read more on the previous question [*"the difference betwen `istreambuf_iterator` and `istream_iterator`"*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26824281/560648).

The example you linked to does also go some way to explaining this.