# Is there a way to read an input string with "ifstream"

Tags: c++, string, file, format, ifstream

Currently my programme takes a string as an input which I access using `argc and argv`

then I use

```
FILE *fp, *input = stdin;
fp = fopen("input.xml","w+b");
    while(fgets(mystring,100,input) != NULL)
    {
        fputs(mystring,fp);
    }
    fclose(fp);
```

I did this part only to create a file **input.xml** which I then supply to

```
ifstream in("input.xml");
    string s((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(in)), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
```

to get `s` as a string(basic string).
Is there a way to feed my input directly to `ifstream`? (i.e feeding a string to `ifstream`).

Comment: No, `ifstream` is designed to read a file. You can use [`std::stringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) if you want to feed a `std::string` as an `istream`.

Comment: [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream)

Comment: It's completely unclear what you're asking for. Do you get the string to read from as argument of you program, or do you want to read a file's content into a `std::string`?

Comment: In my answer below I completely ignore your mention of `argc` and `argv`, which seem to make no sense.

Comment: @user0042 I'm getting it as an argument to my program.

Answer (score 1):

Let me get this straight:

1. You read a string from standard input
2. You write it to a file
3. You then read it from the file
4. And use the file stream object to create a string

That's crazy talk!

Drop the file streams and just instantiate the string from STDIN directly:

```
string s(
   (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(std::cin)),
   std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()
);
```

Remember, `std::cin` is a `std::istream`, and the IOStreams part of the standard library is designed for this sort of generic access to data.

Be aware, though, that [your approach with `std::istreambuf_iterator` is not the most efficient](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3203452/560648), which may be a concern if you're reading a lot of data.

Answer (score 0):

If I get it right then you want to read all the text provided through standard input into a string.

An easy way to achieve this could be the use of `std::getline`, which reads all the bytes up to a specific delimiter into a string. If you may assume that it is text content (which does not contain any `\0`-character), you could write the following:

```
std::string s;
std::getline(cin,s,'\0');
```