# Reading char* from stream - another buffer overflow fiasco?

Tags: c++, io, iostream, buffer-overflow

Today I've discovered that the following compiles and prints 42:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    std::stringstream s;
    s << 42;
    char c[8];
    s >> c;
    std::cout << c;
}
```

But this is a potential buffer overflow attack, right? If we are reading from the user-supplied stream, we can't easily know the size of the data and therefore can't allocate enough storage. `std::gets` was removed, maybe this should be too?

Comment: Maybe related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3203452/how-to-read-entire-stream-into-a-stdstring ?

Comment: This shows the correct way to do this, my question is more about why c++ allows to shoot myself in the foot so easily.

Comment: @M.M `fgets` has a size parameter, this one doesn't.

Comment: @M.M Oh, I didn't know that, I guess you can make it an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can prevent buffer overflow in this case by writing:

```
s >> setw(sizeof c) >> c;
```

So I think it is more akin to the case of `fgets`, which *can be* used to shoot yourself in the foot, but can also be used correctly and it is a perfectly viable option when used correctly.

I expect there is still enough live code that uses this overload of `operator>>` that it's not really viable to deprecate it, e.g.:

```
void func(char *buf, size_t buf_len)
{
    std::cin >> setw(buf_len) >> buf;
}
```

But for writing new code my advice would be to avoid using arrays entirely (C-style arrays, that is). Instead use `std::string`, or `std::array`, or other such containers which are harder to cause buffer overflows on.

Comment: I don't see how using `std::array` changes anything here

Comment: @MooingDuck I was hoping there'd be an overload for `operator>>` with `std::istream` and `std::array` ... if not then there should be :)

Comment: Unfortunately, no C++ container has such an overload, except `std::string` and `std::wstring`