# C++ empty iterator with {}

Tags: c++

I found this answer on stack overflow for [reading a stream into a string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3203502/11365539). The code `std::string s(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(stream), {});` works just fine for what I was doing, but I was really confused about the `{}`. As far as I can tell this is using the `std::string` constructor that uses a begin and end iterator, but I've never seen an iterator defined with `{}`. What does that mean and how is it achieving the same thing as `std::istreambuf_iterator<char> eos;`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`{}` is a braced initialiser list in this context. It is a list of initialisers used to initialise an object. It is used to initialise a temporary object.

In this case, the list of initialisers is empty. In such case, the object will be value initialised. In case of a non-trivially-default-constructible class such as `std::istreambuf_iterator` value initialisation means that the default constructor will be used.

A default consturcted `std::istreambuf_iterator` is a sentinel that represents end of stream. This is a feature specific to stream iterators and not to all other iterators.

Comment: Isn't empty brackets used to avoid [most vexing parse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14077608/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-most-vexing-parse)?

Comment: @Learpcs Yes, there are cases where you can substitute parentheses with curly braces to avoid vexing parses.