# how to read a pipe and put it into a string variable with mingw?

Tags: c++, windows, mingw, pipe

I'm trying to write a simple test program that would do:

```
echo Hello world! | myprogram.exe
```

And the output would be:

```
I heard: "Hello world!". Message length: 12 chars.
```

Comment: @Mat: nothing, I even do not know where to begin, what function to use, there are many examples on the web but they seem very advanced, I thought that on a simple example it would be easier to understand what's going on. I'm very new to C++.

Comment: Then continue searching, use something "C++ read stdin" - lots of hits, including here and a basic I/O tutorial that contains all you need in one web page.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201992/how-to-read-until-eof-from-cin-in-c

Answer (score 1):

Use the input stream std::cin, declared in < iostream >. The exact usage depends on your needs, i.e. you'll need different functions for reading words, characters, whole lines or maybe even all input.

Answer (score 0):

I found, this is the function:

```
string readStdin() {
  stringstream ss;
  string line;
  while (getline(cin, line)) {
    ss << line << endl;
  }
  cin.clear();
  return ss.str();
}
```