# c++ How do I do exception handling in a while loop to pick up typing errors

Tags: c++, class, while-loop, exception

Im trying to eliminated the infinite loop by using exception handling in my code but its not working can someone take a look at this snippet and tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```js
void Addition(float num)
 {
  
  cout<<"Please enter number you wish to add:"<<endl;
  cin>>num;
  
  while( num!=-9999)
  {
   Sum+=num;
   cout<<"Sum is:"<<Sum<<endl;
   cout<<"Please enter number or enter -9999 to exit"<<endl;
   try{
    cin>>num;
   }
   catch(...)
   {cout<<"ERROR"<<endl;
   }
  
   
  }
  
  
 }
```

Comment: Add `num=-9999;` at the end, but inside, the catch block. Or just print out a message that says if you want to exit enter -9999

Comment: The exception is caught inside the while loop, and execution simply continues. If you want the exception to terminate the `while` loop, you must have the try/catch outside of the loop. The entire `while` loop must be inside the `try` block.

Comment: Do try and avoid using *magic numbers* like this. What if someone needed to add `-9999` to the sum? That's what the `eof()` signal is for.

Comment: This code doesn't throw any exceptions. Invalid input puts `std::cin` into an error state which you can test.

Comment: @PeteBecker, good point. His code doesn't show use of an exception mask and the default is not to throw.

Comment: @tadman how do I use eof() to end my program instead of -9999 I'm new at this

Comment: There's [lots of answers in other questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201992/how-to-read-until-eof-from-cin-in-c) on the subject. Have a poke around.

Answer (score 1):

exceptions are only caught if they are thrown first. No part of your code throws any exception using the `throw`keyword. But even if you do that your `catch` block has to be in the loop as well so you have to exit loop using `break` statement if that's your intention

You can do the following

```
void Addition(float num)
    {
        int Sum=0;
        cout<<"Please enter number you wish to add:"<<endl;
        cout<<"Please enter number or enter -9999 to exit"<<endl;

        while( true ) // whcih actually makes it infinite
        {
            try{
                cin>>num;
                if(num == -9999) 
                     throw -9999; // you can throw any value in this case
                Sum+=num;
            }
            catch(...)
            {
             cout <<" ABORTING.."<<endl;
             break;
            }   
        }

       cout << "Sum is:" << Sum << endl;
    }
```

The above code is quite unnecessary it could have done simply like this

```
void Addition(float num)
        {
            int Sum=0;
            cout<<"Please enter number you wish to add:"<<endl;
            cout<<"Please enter number or enter -9999 to exit"<<endl;

            while( true ) // whcih actually makes it infinite
            {

                    cin>>num;
                    if(num == -9999) 
                    {
                       cout << "ABORTING.." << endl;
                       break;
                    }

                    Sum+=num;
            }

            cout << "Sum is:" << Sum << endl;
        }
```

Comment: Even better: `while (std::cin >> num && num != -9999)`.