# Read characters till end of line

Tags: c++, char

Can someone please give me a simple answer on how do I read a characters till the end of the line? I have tried typing

```
cin >> CHAR;

if (CHAR == '\n' || CHAR == '\0') cout << "?" << endl;
```

and none of this work for me, it just ignores this and reads further.

Comment: Do you [search](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7868936/read-file-line-by-line)?

Comment: Use `std::getline()` instead.

Comment: I have been searching but what I find is too advanced and difficult for me, all I need is a simple answer, this has been bothering me for a couple of weeks

Comment: Start with the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io).

Comment: Your use of `CHAR` as a variable name is poor coding standard.  You should have you variable names differ from keywords by more than one case.  Often, readers of your code may think that `CHAR` is a typo of the keyword `char`.

Comment: @umadlol "couple of weeks", "read line cpp" in google. You **REALLY** need to learn how to search.

Comment: possible dupe: [How to read until EOF from cin in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/q/201992/1248974)

Answer (score 0):

As a simple solution, you can do something along the lines of:

```
std::string s;
std::getline(std::cin, s));
for(const char& c : s){
    // Do something with the character
}
```

This will read a single line from `std::cin` and then loop through each character of the line.