# How do I input when no of test cases are not given?

Tags: c++

I was solving this problem on SPOJ.

http://www.spoj.com/problems/NECSTASY/

[Problem Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QI6f2.png)

And this my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
#include <fstream>

const float PI=3.14159265;

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    float d,x,y,t;
    while((cin >> d >> x >> y >>t)!=EOF)
    {
        float u= PI*(t/180);
        float l = (d-y);
        float k = l*(1/sin(u/2));
        float h = k+x;
        cout << fixed << setprecision(2) << h << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am facing a problem with the fact that no of test cases is not given.

How do I deal with that??

Comment: while((cin >> d >> x >> y >>t)!=EOF) .    This won't do that?

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201992/how-to-read-until-eof-from-cin-in-c) for some advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace `while((cin >> d >> x >> y >>t)!=EOF)` with `while(cin >> d >> x >> y >>t)`.

`cin` will evaluate to false when it fails to read.

For more details please read: [std::basic_ios::operator bool](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool)

> Returns true if the stream has no errors and is ready for I/O
>   operations. Specifically, returns `!fail()`.

[EOF](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io) on the other hand is an integer constant expression of type `int` and negative value (macro constant) and would not come equal to `false`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the code for test.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>
const float PI=3.14159265;
using namespace std;
int main()
{
float d,x,y,t;
while(getchar()!=EOF)
{
 cin >> d >> x >> y >>t;
 float u= PI*(t/180);
 float l = (d-y);
 float k = l*(1/sin(u/2));
 float h = k+x;
 cout << fixed << setprecision(2) << h << endl;
}
return 0;
}
```