# How to take variable input from stdin in C++

Tags: c++, string, stdin, getline, eof

I was trying to take input variable number of strings and numbers.Found this solution [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201992/how-to-read-until-eof-from-cin-in-c):

I tried this for **numbers**:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int np;
    while (cin>>np){
        cout << np<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

for **strings:**

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    string line;
    while (getline(cin, line)){
        cout << line <<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But,when I run the code,even if I just press enter it doesn't come out of the loop.The loop should terminate if just an enter key is pressed,but that does not happen.

Please provide suggestions how to achieve this functionality.

Comment: Enter key is still a valid string.

Comment: then how to stop taking input if there is no other left?

Comment: Depends on OS. If memory serves, in Windows it's `Ctrl+Z`, in Unix it's `Ctrl+D`.

Comment: @Abstraction Some are `Ctrl C`  too.

Comment: If you're reading data from a online judge it should put an end of stream in there for you.

Comment: So,the method in the question should work if the EOF is there?

Comment: Yes.  As long as there there is a EOF in the stream they will work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write

```
while (std::getline(std::cin, line) && !line.empty()) {
    // ...
}
```

Only keep looping when the fetched string is nonempty.

Comment: The one downside of this is that the loop breaks on empty lines, which may be undesirable. E.g. if you are a reading from a file and there are extra newlines, the above loop breaks on the first empty newline that is retrieved. But if one wants to read until there is no more input, i.e. until `EOF`, one can replace `!line.empty()` with `!std::cin.eof()`.