# How to read in all whitespaces with cin in C++ into a string?

Tags: c++, string, input, whitespace, cin

Kind of a convoluted question, but is it possible to read input from the user but making cin not stop at newlines or whitespaces? For example, the user can input:

```
Hello  w orld!


Hello World!
```

And I'd want all of the spaces and newline characters input into the string, just basically raw input from the user. Can someone tell me how I could do this in C++? Thanks.

Comment: You can choose another delimiter (end of input), then use `string o; std::getline(cin, o, '-');` ** WHERE "`-`" is the required delimiter, it is a SINGLE CHARACTER **

Comment: Handy reading: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36978839/4581301 which makes [How to read until EOF from cin in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201992/how-to-read-until-eof-from-cin-in-c) a dupe of sorts.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [std::getline](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) for this as shown  :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
  std::string helloWorld;
  std::getline( std::cin, helloWorld );
  return 0;
}
```