# taking input from user in a vector when number of elements is variable

Tags: c++

How do we take input from user in C++ and store in vector when the number of elements is variable?

I know that when we know the number of elements we can use pretty much this code:

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
   cin >> element;
   my_vector.push_back(element);
}
```

But in my case I don't know what the size is going to be, so how can I do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read until EOF from cin in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201992/how-to-read-until-eof-from-cin-in-c)

Comment: That is a dup, but it is a very messy dup...

Answer (score 2):

You can keep looping and adding elements until the stream extraction fails:

```
while(cin >> element)
   my_vector.push_back(element);
```

The loop will terminate when there are no more elements of the appropriate type to be read from `cin`.