# C++ reading from stdin when there is no clear end to input

Tags: c++, stdin

I need to read text from stdin that can be up to 1000 lines long, but potentially less. How can I get this input into one string?

```
string s;
string line;
while (cin) {
    getline(cin, line);
    s += line;
}
```

This runs forever and I can never use string s

Comment: Did you end your input stream?

Comment: This will run until it reaches an EOF.  How else would you know when the input ends if not by some end marker?

Comment: What does "runs forever" means?

Comment: How can I test for EOF?

Comment: Also how can I simulate EOF when entering strings on the terminal

Comment: On Linux you can press Ctrl-D (Bash, zsh, ...). You should have the same behavior on MacOS and on Windows with Git Bash. You can use a code like `while (getline(cin, line)) {s += line;}`. The code from your question won't work correctly. It would read the last line twice. You can read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons Here is an example: https://wandbox.org/permlink/vW4D4aRFXY1ahu10

Comment: Also if you're not expecting an empty line as part of your input, you can use that to break out of the while loop. Just check if line is an empty string and break or something to that effect.

Comment: This is a pretty inefficient way to build your string.  Why not use the `rdbuf` method to read the entire input at once?  Then, since you seem to want newlines removed, you can perform that operation in O(N) time afterwards.

Comment: In CMD it is Cntrl-Z ending copy con file.txt (haven't tested it on above loop) but I always assumed the EOF input convention in MS-DOS and Windows is Ctrl-Z. In above loop you actually test cin=null and I doubt that will ever come.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read until EOF from cin in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201992/how-to-read-until-eof-from-cin-in-c)